# Unable to load data into parquet file format?

Tags: hadoop, hive, etl, hiveql, parquet

I am trying to parse log data into parquet file format in hive , the separator used is "||-||". 
The sample row is
 "b8905bfc-dc34-463e-a6ac-879e50c2e630||-||syntrans1||-||CitBook"

After performing  the data staging I am able to get the result

"b8905bfc-dc34-463e-a6ac-879e50c2e630    syntrans1       CitBook ".

While converting the data to parquet file format I got error :
`

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.PartitionDesc.getDeserializer(PartitionDesc.java:137)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.getConvertedOI(MapOperator.java:297)
        ... 24 more
```

`This is what I have tried`

```
create table log (a String ,b String ,c String)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    "field.delim"="||-||",
    "collection.delim"="-",
    "mapkey.delim"="@"
);
create table log_par(
a String ,
b String ,
c String
) stored as PARQUET ;
insert into  logspar select * from log_par ;
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aman kumar,

To resolve this issue, run the hive query after adding the following jar:

```
hive> add jar hive-contrib.jar;
```

To add the jar permanently, do the following:

1.On Hive Server host, create a /usr/hdp//hive/auxlib directory.

2.Copy /usr/hdp//hive/lib/hive-contrib-.jar to /usr/hdp//hive/auxlib.

3.Restart the HS2 server.

Please check further reference.

https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/150175/errororgapachehadoophivecontribserde2multidelimits.html.

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/79075/loading-data-to-hive-via-pig-orgapachehadoophiveco.html

Let me know,if you face any issues

Comment: Thank you for the help , I pushed my hive-contrib-0.8.1.jar to hdfs:-
then running the above command still getting the same error 
.Right now we are using CDH 5.13.1. 
this is what I have done
"add jar hdfs:///user/amank/jar/sms/hive-contrib-0.8.1.jar ;
insert into  logspar select * from log_par; "

Comment: Did you restart the service after move that jar into hdfs?

Comment: Yes Still getting the same error . Alternatively I tried on spark and converting into parquet But i don't have huge cluster to process around 5.5 TB of data . That's why i am looking to process this using MAP REDUCE.

Comment: Yes it is resolved by using spark but right now we want to use hive becoz we don't have enough memory to process  in spark .